# Extract All Values in Vector

Tags: r

After lot of research I cannot find a solution on extracting values from a dataframe in R without knowing the keys

I have a dataframe named as test which has one vector common (having some json values) and one vector as id. The records are in millions

Example

```
id  common
1   {ename=pageload, pgloc={from=https://m.amazon.com/gift/popular-aloe-vera-plant?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBZh6cWJ1-PGvFC1zMutwfjBJuGROHhW4l_ZtcH3n2ZvPSotsTO-sgxoCucAQAvD_BwE, to=https://m.amazon.com/gift/popular-aloe-vera-plant?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBZh6cWJ1-PGvFC1zMutwfjBJuGROHhW4l_ZtcH3n2ZvPSotsTO-sgxoCucAQAvD_BwE#/product-page, clikd=}, dev={ver=1.0, blang=en-GB, ip=27.5.192.167, dtype=Mobile, ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; HD1901) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.127 Mobile Safari/537.36, did=bc0a2740-d89e-11ea-b35c-567d21f9cbe3, appos=Android, appversion=null, model=null, osver=null, brand=null, pfspec=web}, fngid=81f8036d1099bd59ff93454d1f8, dname=fnp.com, user={cur=, id=sufeb@gmail.com}, wegid=null}  

2 {ename=pageload, pgloc={from=https://www.google.com/, to=https://m.amazon.com/gift/red-velvet-fresh-cream-cake?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBd464AGGzOLMzzaxggCPNU-onDOZuhUqzz3tB6UOIUneNq6rcduxUxoCjXwQAvD_BwE#/product-page, clikd=}, dev={ver=1.0, blang=en-US, ip=106.217.118.179, dtype=Mobile, ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; vivo 1724) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.92 Mobile Safari/537.36, did=d43e7274-8116-11ea-96ae-b627f142e667, appos=Android, appversion=null, model=null, osver=null, brand=null, pfspec=web}, fngid=aeb8d109630f797980ac4cc4066d4c4b, dname=fnp.com, user={cur=, id=}, wegid=null}  
I want to extract all of the values in separate columns in same data frame. Example for id 1 user={cur=, id=sufeb@gmail.com} has values where in id 2 user={cur=, id=} has no values. Hence i would need all values irrespective of keys
```

Tried this but does not works

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rjson)

extract_json_column <- function(test){
  test %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(data = map(common, fromJSON)) %>%
    split(.$index) %>%
    map(~.$common[[1]]) %>%
    map(~map_if(., function(x) length(x) != 1, list)) %>%
    map(as_data_frame) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "index")
}

df <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(test[test != ""], function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(fromJSON(x))))))
```

Error Message

```
 Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
```

A sample Output on keys ename and did. however need for all possible keys like fngid,dtype without typing all the keys

```
id   ename      did  
1  pageload     bc0a2740-d89e-11ea-b35c-567d21f9cbe3  
2  pageload     d43e7274-8116-11ea-96ae-b627f142e667
```

link to data sample
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Gsrq-BCKqRA6csQdQH0duK4olc39TqmnbDYGExhXqo/edit#gid=0

link to gdrive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TxSY97DRT8ih2VJENolar3MJXwtSFTGX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you upload the  `dput(test)` so that we can have reproducible data

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Gsrq-BCKqRA6csQdQH0duK4olc39TqmnbDYGExhXqo/edit#gid=0 link to data

Comment: it seems you already have the test in R. just do `dput(head(test))` and copy the output and paste the output as part of the question. googledocs cannot be directly read into R. Probably drive or github

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TxSY97DRT8ih2VJENolar3MJXwtSFTGX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This doesnot seem to be a valid Json file. You should probably go back to the origin of the file and see whether the words could be quoted. Can you obtain a solution? Yes, though it will be a bit brute forced and ot well dynamic:

Comment: yes that would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224759/discussion-between-ruser-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function in base R:

```
convert_to_json_string <- function(x){
  key_update<-gsub("(?<=[{]|, )(\\w+)=",'"\\1"=', x, perl = TRUE)
  update_vals <- gsub('(?<="=)([^{}"]+)(?=(, ")|[}])','"\\1"', key_update, perl=TRUE)
  update_empty_vals<-gsub('(?<="=)(?=[,}])','""',update_vals, perl=TRUE)
  sprintf("[%s]", toString(gsub('"=', '":', update_empty_vals)))
}
```

then do:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(convert_to_json_string(test$common))
```

The result is too huge to post here but here is the structure:

```
str(jsonlite::fromJSON(convert_to_json_string(test$common)))
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ ename: chr  "pageload" "pageload" "pageload" "pageload" ...
 $ pgloc:'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ from : chr  "https://m.amazon.com/gift/popular-aloe-vera-plant?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBZh6cWJ1-PGvFC1zMutwfjBJuGROHhW"| __truncated__ "https://www.google.com/" "plp~designer-cakes" "" ...
  ..$ to   : chr  "https://m.amazon.com/gift/popular-aloe-vera-plant?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBZh6cWJ1-PGvFC1zMutwfjBJuGROHhW"| __truncated__ "https://m.amazon.com/gift/red-velvet-fresh-cream-cake?gclid=CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBd464AGGzOLMzzaxggCPNU-onDO"| __truncated__ "home" "https://www.amazon.com/" ...
  ..$ clikd: chr  "" "" "back" "" ...
 $ dev  :'data.frame':  10 obs. of  12 variables:
  ..$ ver       : chr  "1.0" "1.0" "1.0" "1.0" ...
  ..$ blang     : chr  "en-GB" "en-US" "en-US" "en-US" ...
  ..$ ip        : chr  "27.5.192.167" "106.217.118.179" "223.237.31.203" "103.240.195.254" ...
  ..$ dtype     : chr  "Mobile" "Mobile" "Mobile" "De
```